# Combining tail and sed command and redirecting them to new file

Tags: shell, sed, tail

I am connecting to multiple remote servers and displaying there log files by using tail command to local system. As all the log files are generating dynamically we are not able to differentiate them. So I am thinking to redirect log file and serevrid to each line of log file to other temporary file and then will tail temporary file, so that on local machine we can differentiate different servers log file.

I am using

```
(sed -e '/s/^/192.168.12.1' /logs/a.log; tail -f /logs/a.log) > b.log
tail -f b.log
```

but now only few starting lines are getting updated with serverid and not all lines after dynamically generating. So kindly tell me how to concatenate serverid with each line of log file.

Comment: You must change `>` to `>>`. And not that this does not guarantee the order of output in final file.

Comment: now also only 1st line is getting concatenated and not all the lines.

Comment: If you are trying to put that IP address at the start of every line of `a.log` you want `sed`.

Comment: @EtanReisner : How to add both commands together. I tried as:        (sed -e 's/^/prefix/' /logs/a.log ; tail -f /logs/a.log ) >> b.log    But as it is dynamically generating, initially only it is concatenating and later it wont.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use syslog to send logs around. Then you get server IPs "for free".

Comment: Yes i am using syslogs but we are not getting server IPs on that.

Comment: sed takes standard input just as well as a file argument. pipe `tail` to it. If you are using forwarded syslog and you don't have IP addresses on the logs I believe that's just a configuration issue.

Comment: @EtanReisner: No configuration issue man. Please give full command as I tried using pipe as well, but its also not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer. I am getting my pattern by using code as:

```
tail -f '/logs/alog' | sed 's/^/'192.168.12.1'/' >> b.log
tail -f b.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed --unbuffered -e 's/^/192.168.12.1/' /logs/a.log >> b.log
tail -f b.log
```

should be enough if you want a file but a simple

```
sed --unbuffered -e 's/^/192.168.12.1/' /logs/a.log
```

will work normaly

Comment: @NeroneLeVelu : In these case only static file is getting updated. But i want to add IP address on log file which is dynamically generating.

Comment: I understand the word but what is the "dynamic" value (in your code) that can be used ? i only see a fixed string that is an IP address like so absolutely not dynamic